# Can I attach file from the Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I was giving a lecture to some students, and they asked about why you are unable to attach a file from the Recycle Bin to an email using Gmail, Yahoo!!, Outlook, etc.

I am using Windows 7, and try to attach file from Recycle Bin, but the folder browser does not show the Recycle Bin for me to be able to access the files within.

How can I attach a file from the Recycle Bin?

Comment: How about moving it out of the Recycle Bin first?

Comment: The 'Recycle Bin' is not a real folder, I doubt there's any way to refer to files in there. For one thing, it has no issue with containing files and folders with identical names - how could you address that? The recycle bin is not a place for files you want to use, it's a staging ground for more permanent deletion.

Comment: Yes, but i was giving lecture to students, they asked me about that.

Comment: *It's not a real folder*. They have no user-exposed file path your browser could use to refer to these files. It's similar with OSX's Trash; it's a collection of all files in the `.Trashes/$Userid` directory of each mounted volume. [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/277979/where-is-the-recycle-bin-in-finder-on-mac-os-x/277982#277982).

Answer (score 6):

Recycle bin is a special folder and not really designed for this.

That being said, if you run whatever your email client`*` is with administrative privileges, you can attach a file from `c:\$Recycle.Bin`... If you can find it in there.

However, I really don't recommend this!

`*` Technically, if using Gmail/Yahoo, your web browser is the email client and the program needing to run with admin privileges.

Comment: I know you are expert and its enough for me. but that would be better if you quote some thing from windows/mac developer.

Comment: I have no idea about Macs and you did not originally give a platform, but, you don't need a quote for everything! This isn't some random theory that will never be proved... You can do the steps I gave and try it for yourself.

Comment: If you want a quote from a Windows/Mac Developers then go to their support. These people are spending their time to help you and all you want is a quote from a Windows/Mac developer!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the file within Recycle Bin and select "Restore", that file will now go back to its original location and then you can attach it to your email client

Comment: i am using computer since i was 8 year old, i know that , but actually I was giving a lecture to students. they asked me why.

Comment: @Abdul that was not present in your question - I then point you to Phoshi as his comment is the best answer for you

Comment: Yes that was after your answer.

Comment: I have amended your question to show to correct information